# flip / invert multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi dimensional array that I want to invert / reverse.
My array contains in the first index 7 days of the week as dates. and each of these days has 16 different records within. I want to convert this into a result of 16 primary results, within these would lie the 7 days of results after.
So from

```
'2015-04-28' => array(
        (int) 1 => (float) 1,
        (int) 2 => (float) 0.5,
        (int) 3 => (float) 0,
        (int) 4 => (float) 0,
        (int) 5 => (float) 1,
        (int) 6 => (float) 1,
        (int) 7 => (float) 0.66666666666667,
        (int) 8 => (float) 1,
        (int) 9 => (float) 0.66666666666667,
        (int) 10 => (float) 0.5,
        (int) 11 => (float) 1,
        (int) 12 => (float) 0.5,
        (int) 13 => (float) 1,
        (int) 14 => (float) 0,
        (int) 15 => (float) 0.5,
        (int) 16 => (float) 1
    ),


to 
 array(
                (int) 1 => array(
                    '2015-04-27' => (float) 1,
                    '2015-04-28' => (float) .67,
                    '2015-04-29' => (float) .5
                ),
                (int) 2 => array(
                    '2015-04-27' => (float) 1,
                    '2015-04-28' => (float) .67,
                    '2015-04-29' => (float) .5
                ),
                (int) 3 => array(
                    '2015-04-27' => (float) 1,
                    '2015-04-28' => (float) .67,
                    '2015-04-29' => (float) .5
                ),
                (int) 4 => array(
                    '2015-04-27' => (float) 1,
                    '2015-04-28' => (float) .67,
                    '2015-04-29' => (float) .5
                ),
            );
```

and so on. Is there a php function available to do this, or would I need to convert this manually?

Comment: no there isn't a function that does it automatically, you'll need to roll up your own function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very hard once you get the hang of associative array.
You can create a new array, and fill the values in a loop like so:

```
function transposeArray($arr) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr as $mKey => $subArr) {
        foreach ($subArr as $sKey => $sVal) {
            $result[$sKey][$mKey] = $sVal;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```